# SQL distinct ID and everything else

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table that contains the following:

```
CUS_ID  A   B
1       1   0
2       2   0
3       3   1
3       1   3
4       2   0
```

Is there a way to write a select statement and grab all the distinct cus_id? So basically it would only bring back one record for cus_id 3.

Comment: How do you tell which one of cus_id 3 rows you want to fetch ?

Comment: What do you want all the distinct IDs or replicating IDs. and what database you are using??

Comment: `select distinct cus_id from yourtable`

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT DISTINCT CUS_ID FROM YourTable`?

Comment: Do you want `A` to be `3` and `B` to be `1` or the other way around? How do you know which of those values you want? If you just want to select distinct CUS_ID then just use `Distinct` and avoid the other two columns.

Comment: I tried doing SELECT distinct(cus_id), a, b - but for some reason its returning both cus_id records

Comment: It doesn't matter which row to bring back because they are they have the same data. (I did not make the table, its not my design)

Comment: you are using distinct as a function while it is just a clause. Try this select distinct .........

Comment: when I remove the parentheses I still get both records.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUS_ID FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
select
    CUS_ID
    -- columns below are optional and exist just to
    -- help you understand for what reason 'group by' is needed
    -- , count(A) cntA
    -- , sum(B) sumB
from YourTable
group by
    CUS_ID
order by
    CUS_ID
```

**UPD**. I meant to comment whole lines :)

Comment: Column A and B are both text. When I try a group by clause I get 'Column 'A' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

Comment: :) it's because these aggregation functions expect numeric values. So just comment these 2 lines (`, count(A)` and `, sum(B)`) query'll work. Or you can try to cast text values in these columns to numeric values, if you want. These lines are here only to show you `group by` usage

Comment: SELECT cus_id, a, b FROM Table
Group By cus_id  -- give me same error